# PHP Script Optimization - MySql Search and Sort

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, sorting

I have developed a fairly simple script to search a database and then sort the results based on the search terms used, so trying to get most relevant first.

Now this ran fine on my local machine and before I put in the sorting ran okay on the web server I have hired but once the sorting went in search times have greatly increased on the webserver.

What I'm posting below I have optimized as much as I know how, so I'm looking for some help in a better sort algorithm and maybe even a better way of querying the database anything to help speed up sort times!

Now some information about what I'm working with I needed to allow searches of 3 letters or more for example cat or car and I couldn't change the natural search word length limit for the mysql server so i can't use natural language searching of mysql hence why I am doing the queries I currently have.

Also an average search can easily return anywhere between 100-15000 results with the databases holding around 20000 entries

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

$bRingtone = true;

$aSearchStrings = $_POST["searchStrings"];

$cConnection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    exit();
}

$sTables = array("natural", "artificial", "musical", "created");

$aQueries = array();

foreach ($sTables as $sTable)
{
    $sQuery = "SELECT filename, downloadPath, description, imageFilePath, keywords FROM `$sTable` WHERE";

    $sParamTypes = "";
    $aParams = array();

    $iCount = 0;

    foreach ($aSearchStrings as $sString)
    {
            $sParamTypes .= "ss";

            $aParams[] = "%,$sString%";
            $aParams[] = "$sString%";

            $sQuery .= $iCount++ == 0 ? " (keywords LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ?)" : " AND (keywords LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ?)";
    }

    array_unshift($aParams, $sParamTypes);

    $aQueries[$sQuery] = $aParams;
}

$aResults = array();

foreach ($aQueries as $sQuery => $aParams)
{
    if ($cStmt = $cConnection->prepare($sQuery))
    {
            $aQueryResults = array();

            call_user_func_array(array($cStmt, 'bind_param'), $aParams);

            $cStmt->execute();

            $cStmt->bind_result($sFileName, $sDownloadPath, $sDescription, $sImageFilePath, $sKeywords);

            while($cStmt->fetch())
            {
                    if ($bRingtone)
                    {
                            $sFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/m4r/" . str_replace(".WAV", ".M4R", $sFileName);
                            if (file_exists($sFileName))
                            {
                                    $sDownloadPath = str_replace("Sounds", "m4r", str_replace(".WAV", ".M4R", $sDownloadPath));
                                    $aResults[$sDownloadPath] = array($sDownloadPath, $sDescription, $sImageFilePath, $sKeywords, $aSearchStrings);
                            }
                    }
            }

            $aResults = array_merge($aResults, $aQueryResults);

        $cStmt->close();
    }
}

$cConnection->close();

$aResults = array_values($aResults);

function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}

function keywordSort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[0] === $b[0]) return 0;

    $aKeywords = explode(",", $a[3]);
    $bKeywords = explode(",", $b[3]);

    foreach ($a[4] as $sSearchString)
    {
        $aFound = in_arrayi($sSearchString, $aKeywords);
        $bFound = in_arrayi($sSearchString, $bKeywords);

        if ($aFound && !$bFound)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if ($bFound && !$aFound)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

usort($aResults, "keywordSort");

foreach ($aResults as &$aResult)
{
    unset($aResult[3]);
    unset($aResult[4]);
}

echo json_encode($aResults);

?>
```

Comment: *"Now this ran fine on my local machine and before I put in the sorting ran okay on the web server I have hired but once the sorting went in search times have greatly increased on the webserver."*

This could be based on your local server's memory/allocation (memory_limit) vs your remote server.

Comment: Yeah i could very well be limited by an extremely low memory limit, I don't remember what it was but definitely less then 256mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting large quantities of data while having to split the field code-side will be slow.  Rather than optimizing, I'd seriously recommend another way of doing it, such as full-text indexing.  It's really quite neat once it's working.

If full-text really isn't an option, I'd recommend splitting the keywords off into a separate table.  That way, you can sort based on a count after grouping.  For example ...

```
SELECT d.*, COUNT(k.id) AS keywordcount
FROM data d
    INNER JOIN keywords k ON (d.id = k.dataid)
WHERE k.value IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3')
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY keywordcount
```

On another PSish type note, you can probably speed up the thing by UNIONing the selects, followed by ordering, rather than running them all independently.